# Moving SVN repo to AWS with new usernames

Tags: svn, amazon-web-services, migration, repository

I have successfully migrated our SVN repo from one in-house server to another, but now am trying to move it up to AWS, and am having a tough time.

I dumped the repo, copied to our EC2 instance and imported it. But... the username for the repository is "subversion" and the EC2 instance uses ec2-user to login and such.

I added a row to the passwd file for SVN with ec2-user and a password, but when I try to connect to the repo I get an error saying no such user exists in the repo.

I also created a user on EC2 called subversion, added it to our svn group, and tried connecting with the subversion username, but I get an error connecting to the EC2 instance.

This seems a pretty trivial issue, but it has me stumped.  Anyone out there know how to resolve this?

Comment: Does SVN support ssh auth for this type of thing? If so, Amazon strongly recommends using ssh keys, and [this guide](http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1233) will take you through generating a new one for a new user, and managing it.

Comment: Yes, and we are using an SSH key.  It **seems** to me that the problem is due to needing to use the ec2-user account with SSH to get in to the server, but needing to use another username/password to access SVN.  I am not sure how to do that with a client like Versions, or any other tool for that matter.

Comment: Did you check out the link I posted? It has instructions for creating ssh-keyed users other than ec2-user, i.e. you should be able to create a 'subversion' user. Search for "useradd". Also possible I've misunderstood your comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this solved.  svnserve had stopped somehow.  Restarting it and pointing it at the proper root solved all of the weirdness.

Thanks for the help, Christopher!